# Composer autoload a package if a condition is met

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I wanted to ask if there's a way to autoload a package ONLY if a condition is met, some of the packages I'm loading are only used for debugging or logging, which is not always needed, removing them from my composer.json freed about 1 MB of memory, so is there a way to set my autoload.php to only require those packages if a certain condition is met.

I know I could edit autoload_files.php but all my changes will be lost whenever I run `composer update` or other composer commands.

So what is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if that your use case, but you do have the possibility to choose which packages are only needed in development (thus not in production): [require-dev](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#require-dev).

basically, when you need a package that is going to be used in dev environment only (like a debugger) you add it with `composer require --dev <package>`.

Hope that helps you.

Comment: "some of the packages I'm loading are only used for debugging or logging" – it sounds like these are the exact right case for dev requirements. (Perhaps not logging, you'd want that in prod. But level could vary)

Comment: Not quiet, my goal is to have certain packages only loaded if I'm logged in as admin for instance, those packages will output debugging information throughout my script, they consume about 1 MB per request which is totally not needed for anyone but the admin.

Comment: I see. So the state of your application is going to define what package to load. I'm not sure how php autoloading is working, but my best guess would be to use a custom auto loader instead of Composer's one.